# make setState in useEffect each time when screen appears

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i have some useEffect function which works when component appeared at first time:

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      try {
        console.log('works');
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        if (token)
          setState({...state, isAuthorized: true})
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```

But how to make it work every time without calling infinite loop, if i remove the empty array from the parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to mention the dependency array as the second parameter to `useEffect()` hook to tell React when you need the `useEffect` to run. The default case is that react will run `useEffect` on every component render/update.

So, if you are running into an infinite loop, its likely that your dependency array is not proper. You are essentially running into case where your useEffect will run, update something in your component, this will trigger a re-render, and then useEffect will run again and this cycle will keep repeating infinitely.

I don't think of any use case where you wouldn't mention the dependency array when you are using the `useEffect` hook. It would always be advisable to mention the list of dependencies as an array to the second parameter of `useEffect` hook or if there are no any dependencies, then you must pass an empty array. This should prevent infinite loop/re-renders from happening in your application.

Comment: above is correct, i would just re-enforce you should never call setState inside useEffect that runs on every render if you don't have a conditional to prevent it from creating an infinite render cycle

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value as the second argument so it will be rendered when that value changes. for example:

```
useEffect(() => {}, [state])
```